# How Do I Add Multiple HTML Files To A (Google Web Toolkit) GWT Project In Eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse, file, gwt

Also keeping in mind the fact as to how to add GWT Widgets To The Secondary HTML Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i hope, i understand you correctly...you can set id for your widget, for example the id "second_html":

```
RootPanel.get("second_html").add(YourScondWidget);
```

And in the second html file you need to set the id for a div

```
<div id="second_html"></div>
```

To insert a second html file you need to edit the web.xml of your project. Example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>second.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: @cupakob Ah! So you add stuff to the RootPanel by there id names rather than also taking into account the file name.  Anyway this was EXACTLY what I wanted.

Comment: i don't know, what you mean with "into account the file name"....but i'm glad that works for you :)

Comment: It referred to the fact that we weren't required to specify the file name of second HTML file when inserting the Widget into the RootPanel. Meaning, we weren't required to write it in the following manner: RootPanel.add({HTML File name},{<id>}); instead, we were only required to specify the <id> of where it is to be place hence, GWT would automatically scan all the present Files stored in the specified Folder and append the Widget according to the <id>.